# Input form name and surname with first letter uppercase

Tags: input, uppercase

I have the code:

```
<input required="required" type="text" class="inp" name="nume" size="30" style="text-align: center" placeholder="Introdu aici numele t&#259;u">
```

The user will introduce his name on a tablet and I want the name and surname  introduced in the field to be with first letters Uppercase. Is that possible? I searched but nothing solid so far.

Cheers and thank you!

Comment: I think I got it: "style: text-transform:capitalize;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure to have understood your question, do you want to force user to introduce names with the first capital uppercase?

Comment: Yes indeed. Sorry for not understanding.

Comment: Yep "style: text-transform:capitalize;" worked. Sorry for the trouble! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const convertName = function (name) {
  return name
    .split(' ')
    .map(
      word =>
        word.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
        word.substr(1, word.length).toLowerCase()
    )
    .join(' ');
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).